# Image scroll upwards

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to make a set of social media buttons which scroll up on hover.

Images are 145px in width and 290px in height. I need only 145px in height shown so that when the image is hovered over, a re-coloured image (the remaining 145px height) pushes the original up (overflow will be hidden i'm assuming).

I know that it's got something to do with transitions and translate properties but I can't quite put my finger on what I need to do.

Could someone help?

I would preferably like to keep it to CSS or HTML unless a jQuery solution is rather simple.

Thanks.

Example image https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwQ9w.png

Comment: You are referring to **sprites**, and you will need to use `background-position` for those. No need to set overflow to hidden, as it will be a background image. And animating should be no problem with css transition. Show us some code and I'll be happy to help!

Comment: I recommend Fontastic these days instead of sprites. It's easy to use, you get more styling flexibility than sprites and icons render at higher quality. http://fontastic.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic implementation with HTML and CSS only, the background being pushed with a transition.

```css
div {
    height: 145px;
    width: 145px;
    transition: background 1s ease;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/X8PyBPp.png") no-repeat left top;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: left bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```